# Dynamically generated form in PyQt

Tags: forms, pyqt5

Let's say I've the following class:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, attributes):
        # Attributes is just a dictionary (string -> value)
        self.attributes = attributes

    def set_attribute(self, attribute, value):
        self.attributes[attribute] = value
        # Some other code which may cause the value of other attributes to change,
        # or other attributes to be added or deleted too
```

Now I'd like to create a PyQt dialog with a simple form, but which is dynamically generated (to account for the variable number of attributes). I did this by creating a QFormLayout in a QDialog and adding a row for every attribute the Person object has:

```
self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
for attribute in self.person.attributes.keys():
      label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
      label.setText(attribute)
      lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
      lineEdit.textEdited['QString'].connect(self.onAttributeChanged)
      # or use a checkbox instead of a line edit if the attribute is a boolean,
      # combo box if it's an enum or similar, etc.
      self.formLayout.addRow(label, lineEdit)
```

Where `onAttributeChanged()` calls `self.person.set_attribute` with the appropriate attribute and the new value inputted by the user.

Now that takes care of updating the model with the user's input values, but the problem I'm facing is how to update the *view* when `set_attribute` modifies the person's other attributes (since `set_attribute` may add or delete other attributes, or change the other attributes' names or values). So far, I've considered to following:

1. Rebuild the *entire* form whenever information changes. There's probably something better than this.
2. Use the Qt signal/slot model, like I did by connecting `lineEdit` to `onAttributeChanged`. From what I understand, this means using `pyqtSignal` to create signals in my Person class representing the attribute names, plus emitting the appropriate signals whenever the names are modified. However, I'd like to keep my Person class intact, and free from any Qt `.emit()` calls. (Not to say this still doesn't handle the case of attributes being added/removed.)
3. Ditch the form altogether and use a table view with a QStandardItemModel instead. Not ideal since I really wanted a *form* and not a *table* (for the sake of better usability).

Is there some elegant way of handling this kind of dynamic form in PyQt?

Comment: If you want to keep you person class separated from Qt, then you need to modify the person class so that one or more callables can be registered with it that the class calls when an attribute is modified. You can then register a reference to `emit` directly or wrap it however you like.